# How can I add colorization for other log-level string/token variations in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

These logs are from any external sources. I use VS Code as a log viewer. I open a file with a `*.log` extension, or create a new file and select log language (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>m</kbd>).

I cannot find how to set colors for log levels when this level has a shorter name.

As you can see below, VS Code applies color for "INFO" or "INFORMATION", but not for "INF" etc.

[image: log levels]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [Log File Highlighter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=emilast.LogFileHighlighter) extension.  It can be customized to handle the different spellings you are using.  For example, this setting (in your `settings.json`):

```
"logFileHighlighter.customPatterns": [
  {
      "pattern": "INFORMATION|INFO|INF",  // more specific works best

      // to restrict with a positive lookahead of the ] character
      // "pattern": "(INFORMATION|INFO|INF|info)(?=\\])",
      "foreground": "#22aa22"
  },
  {
      "pattern": "ERROR|ERR",
      "foreground": "#f00"
  },
  {
      "pattern": "DEBUG|DBG",
      "foreground": "#00f"
  }
]
```

produces this:

[image: log level colors with Log File Highlighter]

There are many style options besides the `foreground` color and any text can be customized.  It also colorizes the logs in the Output view.

Answer (score 0):

For any text views in VS Code using syntax highlighting based on [its builtin "log language"](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/extensions/log), which includes editors for text files with the `.log` extension, and output channels which set their language using the `languageId` argument of [`createOutputChannel`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api), the syntax highlighting will be based on the grammar as defined by [VS Code's "log language"'s textmate grammar file](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/extensions/log/syntaxes/log.tmLanguage.json).

To get different behaviour, you have a couple options:

- Modify the definition of that language. Unfortunately, that file is rather internal to a VS Code installation, so you'd have to dig into the files of your VS Code installation and modify it there to get that, and VS Code would likely then give a corruption warning saying that it detected its files have been tampered with.
- Create a custom VS Code extension that is basically a copy of VS Code's builtin log language extension, but modify it to suit your own needs. Then use the `files.associations` setting to make files with the `.log` extension use your language's ID instead of the ID of VS Code's builtin one. Note that this will have no effect for output panels that set their language to VS Code's builtin one- you have no control over that.
- Or you could [open a feature request issue ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=feature_request.md) asking that the textmate grammar be modified to add support for such token matches.

Comment: These logs are from any external sources. I use vscode as a log viewer - I open file with *.log extension or create a new and select log language (ctrl+k m). It seems that I need to override "match" pattern and it seems that there are no settings available for this, right? I definitely do not want to change vscode internals with losing updates.

Comment: @wdtv see my edit, which clarifies that this answer still applies to your situation now that you clarified, and adds another option for what you can do.

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to it, or notify me in it with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.